# In what circumstances does an investment advisor have to register as a money transmitter?

Tags: finance, cryptocurrency, securities, investment

As far as I understand it, an SEC-registered investment advisor that doesn't hold the client's assets doesn't need extra regulation pertaining to custody. If a robo-advisor like Betterment (although I understand that they're Broker-Dealer-registered) is registered as an RIA and sends client orders straight to the exchange through a broker like Interactive Brokers, do they have to register as a money transmitter? How do the laws change for assets like crypto (sending an order straight to Binance, Coinbase, etc)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I answered my own question. I can change the question but I thought it was pretty clear. A Money Transmitter and a Registered Investment Advisor are pretty well-defined legal entities, meaning my question about when an RIA has to register as an MT seems pretty straightforward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Money Transmitter (MT) is a subset of Money Services Businesses (MSBs) according to the definition of an MSB ([31 §1010.100(ff)](https://www.fincen.gov/money-services-business-definition)). Exempted from inclusion in MSB definition is "a person registered with, and functionally regulated or examined by, the SEC." As an SEC-registered investment advisor, it sounds like such a robo-advisor would not need to register as a money transmitter business as well.